# ScrollViewer's ScrollToVerticalOffset value is not updated in ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset property

Tags: windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, scrollviewer

I have referred the below forum

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1885dcfa-af48-47ee-85d7-bb9809e24f38/scrollviewerscrolltoverticaloffset-not-working-in-windows-8?forum=winappswithcsharp

By invoking ScrollViewer.UpdateLayout() method, we can set the position of scrollviewer in vertical. I can see vertical offset value is changed in UI with/without invoking ScrollViewer.UpdateLayout(). But when i try to get the value from ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset which doesn't gets changed.

```
ScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(1905);
```

// ScrollViewer.UpdateLayout();

Any other way to update this ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recommended way to set vertical / horizontal offset for a `ScrollViewer` is to use [ChangeView()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn252762.aspx) method. Here's how to use it

```
scrollViewer.ChangeView(scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset, 500, scrollViewer.ZoomFactor);
```

You can get the changed `VerticalOffset` or `HorizontalOffset` properties in `ViewChanged` event. E.g.

```
private void scrollViewer_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
{
    double verticalOffset = scrollViewer.VerticalOffset;
}
```

Comment: @Hassan Thank you.

Comment: @Hassan one more query. I have checked the VerticalOffset value by setting the above code and have determined the actual VerticalOffset value of ScrollViewer using ViewChanged event by putting a breakpoint in that event. then the scrollbar getting moved in scrollviewer in UI. But when i checked without a breakpoint, then Vertical scrollbar value is not changed in UI. so have checked by using Task.Delay. this is also not helpful for me.

Comment: In what part of your app you're changing `VerticalOffset`? Make sure UI is loaded when you call `ChangeView()` method.

Comment: @Hassan i'm changing VerticalOffset in button click once ui is loaded. Here i have loaded my custom panel which contains 50 TextBlock with 50 rows.

Comment: I've thoroughly checked but couldn't generate situation like you've described. Try using `RunIdleAsync()` like `await Window.Current.Dispatcher.RunIdleAsync((args) => { scrollViewer.ChangeView(scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset, 500, scrollViewer.ZoomFactor); });`